# ImportError No module named thread

Tags: python

I want to make a simple thread that listens if a Button is pressed or not.

I receive the error `ImportError No module named thread`.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import thread 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN)



def pushButton():
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(17) == 1:
            print("on")
        else:
            print("of")


while True:
    GPIO.output(2,1)
    GPIO.output(3,1)
    time.sleep(1);
    GPIO.output(2,0)
    GPIO.output(3,0)
    time.sleep(1)

thread.start(pushButton,())


GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?  Enter `python --version` to see.  FYI, the `thread` module was renamed `_thread` in version 3 of python.

Comment: thx for answering

Comment: when i change it to import _thread i doesnt't work too

Comment: Do you get the same error message?   Are you using version 3 of python?

Comment: yes i'm using the 3rd version but and no it makes exaclty nothing

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: Could you post the full error message, starting from the line which says `Traceback`

Answer (score 11):

Your original problem is that you are using Python version 3 and according to [this posting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) the `thread` module has been renamed `_thread` in Python 3.

After correcting that issue you state in your comments that the program still doesn't work.

I suspect that is because you never execute the `thread.start(pushButton,())` line of code because the previous block of code is an infinite loop, `while True:` will run the subsequent block of code forever and the thread.start will never get executed.

I recommend that you move the `tread.start` line of code before the `while True` block.  I also recommend that you put some sort of `time.sleep` into your `pushButton` routine otherwise your will continuously output either "on" or "off" very quickly.

I would try:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import _thread 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN)

def pushButton():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if GPIO.input(17) == 1:
            print("on")
        else:
            print("of")

_thread.start(pushButton,())

while True:
    GPIO.output(2,1)
    GPIO.output(3,1)
    time.sleep(1);
    GPIO.output(2,0)
    GPIO.output(3,0)
    time.sleep(1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently learning Python and setting up a server. In the tutorial I'm reading the guy import the thread module this way :

```
from thread import *
```

I'm not telling this is the solution for your problem but we never know. Hope it will help.

Source : http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-server-code-example/